# Create dynamic table with rowspan

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, html, tabular

I am working with React and trying to create a dynamic table. The table looks like this.

[image]

**I am working with this object:**

```
[
{category: "Type One", subCategory: "One", val: 1, rowSpan: 4},
{category: "Type One", subCategory: "Two", val: 2, rowSpan: 4},
{category: "Type One", subCategory: "three", val: 3, rowSpan: 4},
{category: "Type One", subCategory: "Four", val: 4, rowSpan: 4},
{category: "Type Two", subCategory: "Five", val: 5, rowSpan: 2},
{category: "Type Two", subCategory: "Six", val: 6, rowSpan: 2},
{category: "Type Three", subCategory: "Seven", val: 7, rowSpan: 1},
{category: "Type Four", subCategory: "Eight", val: 8, rowSpan: 1},
]
```

This object is dynamic in nature and we may get upto 200 rows. each row will have similar structure.

I have something like this in mind:

```
body = myData.map(function(value) {
    return (
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell> { value.category} </TableCell>
        <TableCell> { value.subCategory} </TableCell>
        <TableCell> { value.val} </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    )
  })

<Table>
   <TableBody>
       {body}
   </TableBody>
</Table>
```

**Questions:**

1. How can I set the row-span for first column to achieve desired result?
2. Does it make sense to create a table to get the desired result or I can use DIV with bootstrap ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are rendering a `<table>`, the `<td>` element has a `rowspan` attribute you can use:

```html
<td rowspan={...}>
```

Of course, only generate that cell for the first row of a "category":

```
body = myData.map((value, i) => {
  const firstOfCategory = (i == 0) || (value.category != myData[i-1].category); 
  return (
    <tr>
      { firstOfCategory && <td rowspan={value.rowSpan}>{value.category}</td> }
      <td>{value.subCategory}</td>
      ...
    </tr>
  );
});
```

Comment: can you explain answer more?... what is the role of the variable "firstOfCategory"?

Answer (score 0):

It look like this:

> ```
> Football  Dragon League 4С…4
> Dragon League 4С…4
> Football  FIFA 20. Amateur daily league
> Football  FIFA 21. eSports Battle. International B
> FIFA 21.    eSports Battle. International B
> Football  FIFA. Elite League
> Football  Kazakhstan. Premier League
> Kazakhstan. Premier League
> Football  KLASK
> ```

i.e duplicated values are not going to the second columns.